# How to change external URL on MAPI over HTTP on Exchange 2016?

Tags: exchange, outlook

I have setup a new Windows 2012 R2 server and installed Domain Controller and Exchange 2016 on it with all that needed.

Yes i know, i should not have domain controller on same server as exchange server but thats not my problem everything works except Outlook on Windows can not run MAPI over HTTP becouse when it trying MAPI over HTTP its trying on my domain controller domain name and exhangeserver hostname so its trying to connect to WIN-XXXXXX.XXXXX.local  but my external url for my webserver is mail.mydomain.com but something doing that my outlook trying MAPI over HTTP to that wrong url that not exist.

I have tried to searched and searched but can not find where to change the external URL for MAPI over HTTP, everything else runs on my external url but not MAPI over HTTP.

Any ideas?

Edit:

After discuss this with a friend that worked with Exchange for long time he figure out that under the ECP web interface  there is a menu called Servers there you select your server and geting a small window with some new left menu where you have Outlook Anywhere, here you can type your external url and internal url for Outlook Anywhere.

Thats fixed my problem.

Answer (score -1):

You cannot configure most of the URLs within ECP - some of them have to be done through the Shell. Therefore while you have modified the ones that you can see, you will still have problems, particularly with Autodiscover.

I have a guide on what you have to change here: http://semb.ee/hostnames2013 - it is written for Exchange 2013 but also applies to Exchange 2016.